# VB.Net Picture Box Control

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

OK so currently this is the code I have below of a picture box

```
PxBx.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ThisProject\ThisProject\Images\filename.JPG")
```

What is the correct syntax for using images files stored in the application files after i publish a project? Namely b/c this path will not always be the same based off when/where users would store the app files?

I did a bit of searching but havent figured out how to ask the correct question to get the answer from forums/google.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add to your Settings.settings a new entry for the path to the folder where you store the images. This setting will be read at runtime and used to find your images. The advantage of this approach is that you can manually (or through your setup code) change the config file (where the setting is stored) to whatever your customer requires. Instead, hard coding a path (relative or not) inside the code is just a problem waiting to happen.

To add an entry in your setting.settings file right click your project and select properties, then the settings tab. Here, add a Name like "ImagePath", of Type = String and Scope = "Application", then set your current path as value and save.

Now, if you open the app.config (or web.config) file you will see the new entry and its value. To use it at runtime

```
string imagePath = Properties.Settings.Default.ImagePath;
```

Comment: Whats the difference between your suggested method and adding it as a resource? Sorry for newb question, I am asking so that I understand not only rhyme/reason but to help me set up best practice habits

Comment: I have explained the reason. If you hard code the path you cannot change it to a different location. Suppose that your customer wants to store all images in a LAN location named **\\SERVERNAME\APPLICATIONS\DATA** That's not possible with an hard coded path both with absolute paths and relative or partial paths

Comment: Adding the image as a resource is another viable option. Of course this is good only if the images are read-only and what your application is doing with these images. Good for icons on buttons or other small glyphs used by the app. Not good, for example, for a logo or for every situation where the final user needs to choose its own images

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the image to the project.
You have 2 ways:

1. Create a folder in your solution explorer called Images or whatever you want. Right click on it and click 'Add Existing Item'. Choose the image you want.

   Then type in your code:

   ```
   PxBx.Image = Image.FromFile("Images\FileName.jpg")
   ```

2. Click on your project name in the solution explorer. It will take you to a new "screen" (I don't know how to call it), from the right click on 'Resources', from there you can add your image.

   Then you reference it in your code using:

   ```
   PxBx.Image = My.Resources.Filename
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the [**`Application.StartupPath` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx) and use [**`Path.Combine()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx) to construct a proper path:

```
PxBx.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Images", "filename.JPG"))
```

Comment: Whats the advantage of doing it this way? Is this a best practice? Can i get a little bit more information?

Comment: @DougCoats : There isn't really a "best practice" when it comes to things like these because it differs depending on what you do and what you need. The only "best practice" thing here is the use of `Path.Combine()` as it will construct a proper path, and if you enter something invalid it'll throw an exception.

Comment: @DougCoats : `Application.StartupPath` is just one out of the many ways you can get the application directory. -- For deeper info on how these two work, check the links in my answer.